# Entity Framework OnMyPropertyChanged called when materializing the object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

If I have a property called Banana in my entity class, EntityFramework generates a partial method called OnBananaChanged() that I can implement.

Unfortunately, this seems to be called even when the entity first materializes from the database (i.e. is being constructed).

Is there a non-hack way of dealing with this? I only want to execute special behavior when the property is changed after the entity has already been constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Expose custom property or method on your entities. This method will turn on or off your handler. Handle `ObjectMaterialized` event on the `ObjectContext` and call the method on your entity. There is no build-in way to stop this behavior.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my issue. I want to know when a property changes. Unfortunately, the OnMyPropertyChanged() method is called when the object is materialized -- giving me a false indication that the property has changed - because it really hasn't, it was just materialized.

Comment: But first time setting a property is a change in this case. It changed from default value to value loaded from the database and because of that you must turn on your event after the object was materialized.

Comment: "Turn on your event"? What event? There is a partial method called OnMyPropertyChanged (e.g. OnBananaChanged() ), that I implement. It gets called by Entity Framework.

Comment: That method is called in each property setter so you simply have to add some additional logic to your method implementation. Your method must execute its logic only if entity has already been materialized = you will have some flag on entity which you set in mentioned handler.